# How to check if a^b is smaller than n

Tags: algorithm, exponentiation

given 2 positive integers **a** and **b** (1 < a,b < 10000), I want to make sure **a^b < 10000**.

the problem is I can't just solve a^b, given that 64^64 is long enough to break integer size.

how can I have this answer fast? I thought about using exponentiation by squaring but I didn't come up with an answer yet.

thanks

Comment: When `10000`'s logarithm to the base `a` is greater than `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the a-base logarithm of both sides of the inequality.

For positive integers *a* and *b*, the following inequalities are equivalent:

*a<sup>b</sup> < 10000*

*log<sub>a</sub>(a<sup>b</sup>) < log<sub>a</sub>(10000)*

*b < log<sub>a</sub>(10000)*

The latter can be calculated without overflow issues.

Note also that with the [*change of base formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) this can be written with a *log<sub>10</sub>* function:

*b·log<sub>10</sub>(a) < 4*

Comment: Note that calculating logarithm may require to leave domain of integers so there may be precision issues

Answer (score 6):

Since both `a` and `b` are *integers* we can conclude that

1. Special case `a = 1`

   ```
    a ^ b < 10000 for any b
   ```
2. Other `a` values can be organized into a simple table

   ```
           a | critical b
   -----------------------------
           2 |    13
           3 |     8
           4 |     6
        5..6 |     5
        7..9 |     4
      10..21 |     3
      22..99 |     2
   100..9999 |     1
     10000.. |     no solutions
   ```

So, having, say `a = 4`, `b = 7` we can conclude that `4**7 > 10000` since `b = 7` is more than critical value (`6`) for `a = 4`

Answer (score 2):

Considering a,b positive:

You may set variable `result` to 1 and then multiply it by `a` `b` times.
Once it's more than `10000` it will always be so you may return

The value of `result` will never be more than 10000 squared witch fits integer types. (unless a is greater than that, but it means you will return immediately).

If `a>1` then it'll require no more then log<sub>2</sub> 10000 iterations

If `a = 1` then you know that a<sup>b</sup>=1 immediately too

Comment: I was thinking this, too, but `a` might be given as 10 gazillion, so start with `result=a` and multiply `b-1` times.

Comment: @danh: `a` is given so it will fit some type (typeof(a)), so it still can't overflow. This way you don't have special case for b = 0 (I know I said assume b positive)

Comment: Right, not that 10 gazillion overflows, but in case the first product would (10 gazillion squared).  We save the first iteration of the loop, and avoid the overflow on the first product.

Comment: what I meant both your and mine algo would not calculate 10 gazillion squared. Anyway, choosing one is a matter of style

Comment: I don't think so.  `result=a;  iteration=0; while(result<1000 && iteration<b-1) {...}` we never get to the body of the loop when a is almost overflowinishly large.  (i wish i could up vote here again.  i think this is a superior answer from the standpoint of practical computation).

Comment: @danh, unless I miss what youmean, in my case we enter it once, but only thing we will do is to multiply by 1

Answer (score 1):

If `a>1`, then there are only a few valid exponents, so you might as well just look up the largest valid value of `a` for each one:

```
maxBases=[0,9999,99,21,9,6,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2];
if (b<1)
    return true;
if (b>13)
    return (a <= 1);
else
    return (a <= maxBases[b]);
```